# Basic numbers and minimisation

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Given $a$ and $b$ find $c$ and $d$ such that $bc-ad$ is least and greater than zero?
Also $a,b,c,d$ are integers and all lie inside a given range i.e. $[0, n]$.

For example, if $n=50, a=48$ and $b=49$, then $c=49$ and $d=50$.

One more example: if $n=1, a=1$ and $b=1,$ then $c=1$ and $d=0$

Any hints?

Comment: What did you try? Did you observe that $bc - ad \geq 0$ if and only if $\frac{b}{a} \geq \frac{d}{c}$?

Comment: yes, it is obvious...

Comment: If it helps, note that $ad-bc$ is the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$, and that you can interpret the absolute value of the determinant as the area of the parallelogram spanned by the two vectors $[a\ c]^T$ and $[b\ d]^T$. Thus, you are given the $x$-coordinates of two vectors, and you are looking for the $y$-coordinates that make the spanned parallelogram have the least possible area.

Comment: @Surb, i am new to stackexchange. Thanks for clarifying the rules.